# Enable sssd caching and linux to honor that cache on CentOS 5

Tags: centos, authentication, sssd, caching

I wanted to enable sssd caching on CentOs and not to use nscd caching, because sssd itself is giving that option. However, authconfig is not giving the option for --enablecachecreds even on the highest version of authconfig available on Centos 5.8. Is caching enabled via pam? If so, where to look up for more details, or how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Does not sssd cache automatic?
I have never needed to configure the cache any way,
but sometimes I need to clear it using `sss_cache -U`

Cache files should be stored in /var/lib/sss/db/, so if you find your domain there, then sssd would cache.

Comment: Not until you have cache enabled. On versions prior to 6, the authconfig doesn't have option to enable sssd caching (I guess authconfig honors the sssd cache via pamd only). If you stop the sssd daemon even with `cache_credentials = True`  enabled, offline logins till the cache expiration are not happening, and debug log shows a lookup everytime.